# When find() of tbb::concurrent_hash_map is used in parallel with iteration, the amount of data obtained is inconsistent with the size of the map?

Tags: c++, concurrenthashmap, tbb

I have two threads, one is doing `find()` on a `tbb::concurrent_hash_map` and the other is traversing this map without doing any insertion or deletion. The strange thing is that if `find()` is not executed, the iterative traversal is normal, but when `find()` is executed, the amount of data obtained by iteration using `HashMap::iterator` is inconsistent. Why is this happening?

(tbb version 2021.5.0-7ubuntu2.)

I added a test example, including two pieces of code. One is where I encapsulated `tbb::concurrent_hash_map`, and the other is a test example. The results are as follows:

```
writeTime=0.367443
------------finish write---------------

 hashMap size = 3174014
 trav_cnt=3480029

 error: trav_cnt=3480029 hashmap_size=3174014
-----readTime=2.19917
```

test code:

```
#include<map>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
#include<fstream>
#include<iostream>
#include <omp.h>
#include <tbb/concurrent_hash_map.h>
#include <tbb/tbb.h>

template <typename KeyType, typename ValueType>
class ConcurrentHashMap {
  private:
    typedef tbb::concurrent_hash_map<KeyType, ValueType> HashMap;
    typedef typename HashMap::const_accessor HashMapConstAccessor;
    typedef typename HashMap::accessor HashMapAccessor;
    typedef typename HashMap::iterator HashMapIterator;
    typedef typename HashMap::value_type HashMapValuePair;

  public:
    ConcurrentHashMap (ValueType default_value) : DEFAULT_VALUE(default_value) {
    }

    size_t size() {
      return hashMap.size();
    }

    bool insert(const KeyType& key, const ValueType& value) {
      HashMapAccessor accessor;
      bool inserted = hashMap.insert(accessor, key);
      if (inserted) {
        accessor->second = value;
      }
      return inserted;
    }
    bool erase(const KeyType& key) {
      return hashMap.erase(key);
    }

    bool find(const KeyType& key, ValueType& value) {
      HashMapConstAccessor accessor;
      if (hashMap.find(accessor, key)) {
        value = accessor->second;
        return true;
      }
      value = DEFAULT_VALUE;
      return false;
    }

    void clear() {
      hashMap.clear();
    }

    const ValueType& operator[](const KeyType& key) const {
      HashMapConstAccessor accessor;
      hashMap.find(accessor, key);
      if (hashMap.find(accessor, key)) {
        return accessor->second;
      }
      // accessor->second = DEFAULT_VALUE;
      return DEFAULT_VALUE;
    }

    HashMapIterator begin() {
      return hashMap.begin();
    }

    HashMapIterator end() {
      return hashMap.end();
    }

  private:
    HashMap hashMap;
    ValueType DEFAULT_VALUE;
};

class A;

using HashMap = ConcurrentHashMap<int, A*>;
// using HashMap = ConcurrentUnorderedMap<int, A*>;

class A {
public:
  A(int _a, int _b): a(_a), b(_b) {

  }
  void sub () {

  }
  int a = 1;
  int b = 0;;
};

void test(int N, HashMap& hashMap) {
  int thread_num = 16;

  std::thread writer(
    [&] () {
      auto writeStartTime = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
      #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(thread_num)
      for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        hashMap.insert(i, new A(1, i));
      }
      auto writeEndTime = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
      double writeTime = std::chrono::duration<double>(writeEndTime 
                                                      - writeStartTime).count();
      std::cout << "writeTime=" << writeTime << std::endl;
    }
  );

  writer.join();
}

int random_uniform_int(const int min = 0, const int max = 1) {
  unsigned seed = 2000;
  static thread_local std::mt19937 generator(seed);
  std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(min, max);
  return distribution(generator);
}

int main () {
  // cmd: g++ test_con_hashmap.cpp -fopenmp -ltbb  && ./a.out
  int N = 3174014;
  std::nullptr_t NULLPOINTER = nullptr;
  HashMap hashMap(NULLPOINTER);

  test(N, hashMap);

  std::cout << "------------finish write---------------" << std::endl;

  size_t hashmap_size = hashMap.size();
  std::cout << "\n hashMap size = " << hashmap_size << std::endl;

{ 
  int thread_num = 32;
  std::thread reader(
    [&] () {
      std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1));
      auto readStartTime = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

      for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
        #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(thread_num)
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
          A* value;
          int randomKey = random_uniform_int(0, N - 1);
          if(hashMap.find(randomKey, value)){
            
          }
        }
      }
      auto readEndTime = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
      double readTime = std::chrono::duration<double>(readEndTime 
                                               - readStartTime).count();
      std::cout << "-----readTime=" << readTime << std::endl;
    }
  );

  size_t trav_cnt = 0;
  for(auto iterator1 = hashMap.begin(); 
      iterator1 != hashMap.end(); ++iterator1 ){
    trav_cnt++;
  }
  std::cout << " trav_cnt=" << trav_cnt << std::endl;

  if (trav_cnt != hashmap_size) {
    std::cout << "\n error: trav_cnt=" << trav_cnt
              << " hashmap_size=" << hashmap_size
              << std::endl;
  }


  reader.join();
}

  hashMap.clear();

  return 0;
}
```

I want to know why the read operation of `find()` affects the traversal operation?

Comment: Please say what version of TBB you are using.  I also highly recommend running your test program with Thread Sanitizer, maybe it will give you a clue.

Comment: @JohnZwinck Thank you very much for your reply. I am using tbb version 2021.5.0-7ubuntu2.

Comment: In the omp loop, you are drawing random numbers in parallel via `dis(gen)`. This is undefined behavior. The C++ standard RNGs do not allow parallel drawing of numbers.

Comment: @Sedenion Thanks for your correction, I fixed the issue with random number generation. However, my confusion about tbb still exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the iterations over TBB ConcurrentHashMap [are not thread safe](https://spec.oneapi.io/versions/latest/elements/oneTBB/source/containers/concurrent_hash_map_cls/iterators.html):

> All member functions in this section can only be performed serially.
> The behavior is undefined in case of concurrent execution of these
> member functions with other (either concurrently safe) methods.

TBB concurrent_unordered_map has safe iterations, but it lacks `erase`.

There was an interesting blog on the reasons by Anton Malakhov, but one is buried somewhere inside intel.com.

EDIT: [explanation of pitfalls saved by the Archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20200818130444/https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/blogs/traversing-concurrent_hash_map-concurrently.html)